# How to delete or remove a key from mapping?

Tags: solidity, mapping

I have the following map:

```
mapping (string => Category) categoryMap;
```

Let's say the key was mistyped, so I want to remove the key and add a correct one, how would I do that?

Function would be

```
  function updateCategoryLabel(string _newCategoryLabel, string _oldCategoryLabel) {
    categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel].label = _newCategoryLabel;
    Category tmpCategory = categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel];
    // Delete Key
    // create new key from _newCategoryLabel
      }
```

Thanks

Edit:

Here is what I was doing:

```
  function updateCategoryLabel(string _newCategoryLabel, string _oldCategoryLabel) {
    categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel].label = _newCategoryLabel;
    Category tmpCategory = categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel];
    delete categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel];
    categoryMap[_newCategoryLabel] = tmpCategory;
  }
```

Category struct

```
  struct Category {
    string label;
    uint percent;
    address[] userList;
  }
```

Comment: The answer below is correct per say (i.e., for the given question), but if we look beyond this question - you don't need to delete the entry (key + value) if you plan to override it immediately after.

Comment: @goodvibration but then how do I update the key. Let's say the og key is "prson" and I want the key to be "person" but have the same value, how would I just update/edit the key?

Comment: Then you wouldn't be updating the value of the existing key (`"prson"`), you'd be mapping a value to a new key (`"person"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function updateCategoryLabel(string _newCategoryLabel, string _oldCategoryLabel) {
    categoryMap[_newCategoryLabel] = categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel];
    delete categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel];
```

Comment: You might want to add that technically, there's no need to delete the entry (key + value) if the plan is to override it immediately after.

Comment: @Edmund Edgar that's what I was doing so far, but doesn't it just delete the value linked to the key _oldCategoryLabel when you do so?

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: You'd need to copy that value first.

Comment: @goodvibration that's what I did. I updated my main post!

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: I can see your code in your question. It's all messed up - you are trying to assign the new key to the old key's value. If they're not of the same type, then this code won't even compile. If they are of the same type, then - even worse - you'll probably get extremely undesired behavior, without understanding why.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Line by line, I'm updating my value.label to the new one, then I'm copying this whole value in a new one, then I'm deleting the key and then I'm assigning the copied value to the new key. That's what I think I'm doing atleast.

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: The line `categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel].label = _newCategoryLabel;` is a mess, because the LHS type is `Category` and the RHS type is `string`.

Comment: @goodvibration Added the category struct in main post. categoryMap[_oldCategoryLabel].label is a string

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: You want to create a new key with the same value, and then delete the old key (along with the old value of course). The variables that you pass to the function represent the old key and the new key, right? (btw, you probably want to rename them from "Label" to "Key"). In the line that I mentioned, you are setting the label of the old key to the new key. That would lead to a mess, like I said. Definitely not the behavior that you are trying to achieve.